# Does fork carry threads along?

Tags: linux, pthreads, fork

Suppose in POSIX semantics, I have a process A, it has two threads, t1 and t2. t1 is the main thread, then, in t2 I call fork to fork process B.

Then does this new process B have t1 and t2 too? Or it just have t2?

In other words, does fork duplicate multiple threads to new process as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child process is created with a single thread--the one that called fork(). The entire virtual address space of the parent is replicated in the child, including the states of mutexes, condition variables, and other pthreads objects; the use of pthread_atfork(3) may be helpful for dealing with problems that this can cause.

[Man 2 fork Manual](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)

Comment: Your answer: only the thread that called the fork() will be copied as a new process